# simulacro de funcion strncpy

Tags: c, string, codeblocks

Hice una funcion que simula hacer lo que realiza strncpy de la libreria string. Copio una n cantidad de caracteres de una palabra en otra. Pero no quiero modificar la cadena original...y lo hace. No puedo encontrar la forma de no modificarla.Les paso la funcion:

```
char * mistrncpy(char * cad2,
  const char * cad1, int cant) {
  const char * cadaux1;
  int i = 0;
  for (cad2 = cad1; i < cant; i++);
  if (i == cant) {
    *(cad2 + i) = '\0';
    return cad2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Te digo lo mismo que en la otra respuesta. Si no quieres modificar la cadena original tienes que usar memoria dinámica y luego acordarte de liberarla... ¿realmente quieres hacer eso? Piensa que si la función original no lo hace será por algo.

Answer (score 0):

Una opcion algo chapucera podria ser esta que te presento, seguro te sirve para darte una idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(const char* src,char* dest, int max){

   int index = 0;

    while(src[index]!='\0' && index<max){
        dest[index] = src[index];
        index++;
    }
    dest[index]='\0';//NULL
}

int main()
{
    char str1[] = "hello world";
    char str2[100];

    copy(str1,str2,9);//copia solo 9 caracteres
    printf("%s\n",str2);
    printf("%s\n",str1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Crack81 !! Voy a tenerlo en cuenta!